# Attempting to get the image property via jquery traversal but am getting undefined

Tags: jquery

I am trying to traverse the DOM with jQuery, but I am getting `undefined`. This is the code:

```js
alert($('#para1').childNodes[1].nodeName);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="para1">
  <img src=........>
</p>
```

What is the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are so many ways to get the `img` element and the attributes ...

```
$('#para1 img').attr("src");
// or
$('img', $('#para1')).attr("src");
// or
$('#para1').find("img").attr("src");
// or
$('#para1').children("img").attr("src");
/// ...
```

If you want the tag name, replace `.attr("src")` with `.prop("tagName")`.

```
$('#para1').children().each(function() {
    alert($(this).prop("tagName"));
});
```

To loop child elements by an `index` there are even many, many ways to do this. Just some possible ways:

```
// using the index with :eq()
var tag = $("#para1 *").eq(0).prop("tagName");

// another way using :eq()
var tag = $("#para1").children().eq(1).prop("tagName");

// another way using :eq()
var tag = $("#para1 :eq(2)").prop("tagName");

// using DOM elements out of jQuery
var tag = $("#para1").children().get(0).tagName;

// another way using DOM elements out of jQuery
var tag = $("#para1").children()[1].tagName;

// another way using DOM elements out of jQuery
var tag = $("#para1 *")[2].tagName;

// create a arra map out of all children
var tags = $("#para1").children().map(function() {
    return $(this).prop("tagName");
}).get();
```

**[Working example.](https://jsfiddle.net/8f65qe16/1/)**

Comment: Thats really helpful. but u was woundering if it was actually possible to use an array with index with the children method, since the p tag could have  more than one child

Comment: You're welcome, @pedroyanky! Could you explain what you want to have? I'm not shure I'm understanding what you want. Tell me what your result should be and I will give you a solution ...

Comment: always having problem traversing the DOM, what i was trying to achieve was to use array index with the square bracket to get the children,

Comment: Here are differnt ways to do this: https://jsfiddle.net/8f65qe16/1/ @pedroyanky. Hope this helps ...

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#para1').children().get(0).tagName
```